# Conexión SQL Server Nodejs

Tags: nodejs

Quiero conectarme a un servidor SQL Server Local este no tiene usuario y contraseña se conecta por Windows , con mssql en Nodejs pero no puedo

```
const dbAplicativo = {
    Aplicativo: {
        user: '',
        password: '',
        database: 'db_innovacion',
        server: '(LocalDb)\LocalDemo',
        port: 1433
    }
}

exports.connectionStringAplicativo = dbAplicativo.Aplicativo;
```

Comment: ¿Qué driver de conexión estás usando?

Comment: Es importante agregar detalles a tu pregunta, recuerda responder a los que tratan de ayudarte, saludos.